# using lmer predict in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, predict, lme4

```
  library(lme4)
  library(data.table)
  library(dplyr)

  d = data.frame(x = rep(1:100, times = 3),
                 y = NA,
                 grp = rep(1:3, each = 100))

  d$y[d$grp == 1] = 1:100 + rnorm(100)
  d$y[d$grp == 2] = 1:100 * 1.5 + rnorm(100)
  d$y[d$grp == 3] = 1:100 * 0.5 + rnorm(100)

  fit = lmer(y ~ x + (x|grp), data = d)

  new.data <- data.frame(x = 1:100, grp = rep(1:3, each = 100))
  new.data1 = new.data %>% dplyr::mutate(grp = 1)
  new.data2 = new.data %>% dplyr::mutate(grp = 3)

  temp <- new.data %>% 
          dplyr::mutate(predV1 = predict(fit, newdata = new.data1, allow.new.levels = TRUE),
                        predV2 = predict(fit, newdata = new.data2, allow.new.levels = TRUE))
```

My actual `new.data` has many more predictors, groups, more observations to predict on (~10000 rows)
and hence the above dplyr solutions takes around 34 seconds. 
I wondered if lmer predict function can be used with data.table to speed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need  a similar approach in `data.table`, convert to `data.table` (`setDT`) and assign (`:=`) the output of `predict` to the new columns 'predV1', 'predV2'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(new.data)[, c('predV1', 'predV2') :=
     .(predict(fit, newdata = new.data1, allow.new.levels = TRUE), 
       predict(fit, newdata = new.data2, allow.new.levels = TRUE))]
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. After I posted the question, I realised whether a data.table solution is fast or not then the dplyr solution?

Comment: you can check it easily with system.time or microbenchmark